# How to insert Array to Database using firstOrCreate in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach, eloquent

I have an array  like this and it has 120 elements in it

```
`array (size=120)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      'name' => That the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy - 7' (length=53)
      'url' => string 'google.com/zyx' (length=134)
      'category' => string 'search-engine' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=8)
      'name' => string 'Mr. john brandy gave me a wall nut of quite' (length=67)
      'url' => string 'yahoo.com/dzxser' (length=166)
      'category' => string 'indian' (length=6)`
```

I want to insert them to my bookmark table which model I have created and I want to make sure duplication doesn't occur. I have found this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#other-creation-methods specially `firstOrCreate` method.

I assume I have to use foreach but I am not sure how. Can anyone help me with some workaround.

Comment: nothing duplicate here

Comment: @AbdullaNilam I know but it is an example having only 2 elements of the array. I told it consists 120 elements in total or may contain more elements.

Comment: check this http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/using-eloquentfirstorcreate-to-prevent-duplicate-seeding and this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/first-or-create-result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need `firstOrCreate`, you need `updateOrCreate`. Checking Laravel [Other Creation methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#other-creation-methods) You will find that method.

[image]

Say that array is in `$alldata`:

```
foreach($alldata as $data) {
    MyModel::updateOrCreate($data); //the fields must be fillable in the model
}
```

This will run update/or create of 120 queries while cycling through the loop. The advantage is that, you cannot have a duplicate, rather if there is a repetition, its only going to perform an update to the table.

However the best way to ensure that there is no duplication in whatever way the data comes is to set it up when making your database table. You can set unique constraints on many fields if thats your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want duplication to occur when inserting array of records then all you have to do it set a constraint making sure fields are unique.

If you're using migrations to create databse schema you can use something like this: `$table->string('name')->unique();`

Now for example, this will make sure that 'name' column data is

Comment: I don't want to set constraint. I want to use firstorCreate method.